# SCNView becomes UIView after using Storyboard?

Tags: swift, scenekit, xcode-storyboard

So, I've encountered some kind of strange interaction with SceneKit and the Storyboard, apparently. That, or it has something to do with the "game" preset when creating a new project.

Whenever I use the storyboard, when I try to create a SCNView, it becomes a UIView, and causes my code to error out. In experimenting with the storyboard, I tried adding a button to see if I could find a way to make tapping the left side of the screen do something, tapping the right do something else, etc. etc. but as soon as I did, 1) the button took up the entire SCNView and refused to change dimensions when I tried to resize it, and 2) my SCNView became a UIView, even though I didn't change the actual code that was written in the .swift file.

To confirm this, I started a new project, copy and pasted the code, and found that it still works just fine in this second project where I hadn't touched the storyboard. I even tried deleting the button I created on the first project, but it seems like the damage was already done.

So, does using the storyboard alter the properties of objects in your code? I've been trying to find more information, but everything I've found on the storyboard has to do specifically with UIKit, not SceneKit.

Comment: Can you post your skeleton project?

Comment: @Chris Do you mean, the code that I'm using between both of the projects?